# Sending Object with Jms - HornetQ (performance issue)

Tags: jms, hornetq

Which one is better in performance for sending object message?

1. Create ObjectMessage and send it.
2. Serialize Object to xml, create TextMessage, and send xml content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your object to bytes and send it.

Serialization sucks...
XML Sucks

If you use ObjectMessage, make your objects externalizable and avoid writeObject inside the externalizable, than your conversion will fly.

Manual parsing to bytes is what would get you the best performance. And this is not just hornetQ (any JMS Server out there). Serialization sucks! (I"m also the author of JBoss Serialization, so I know what I"m talking about... not much for the JBoss name on it, but I know the inner works of serialization)

Someone would have to come up with a code generation serialization in order to make things fly.

Comment: Thank u! So i should use BytesMessage?

Comment: It's hard for me to say what you should use. BytesMessage is definitely the fastest (everything else in a messaging server is converted to a byte array somehow, so a pure byte arrays messages is always the fastest). However you should measure the benefit of the speed against the processing power you have versus the amount of code you will have to make. i.e. you will have to do your home work accordingly.


For this reason I believe why George Stocker closed this question. Your questions is way too generic and hard to pin point to a single answer.

Comment: @Clebert Well I won't be reading your books then.  Anyone who knows anything about EAI knows binary encoding is an anti-pattern. http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/

Comment: I'm talking about Object Serialization.. Use Text message, Stream Message.. anything you like.. but ObjectSerialization will bring you a big pitfal in performance.

If you rather sacrifice in performance and use a big Java Serialization.. got ahead.